# Cast list<Object> to an ArrayList

Tags: java, hibernate, list, arraylist, casting

i've a error cast.

My console's error is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to modelAjax.ModeloAjax

My code is:

**DAO**

```
public List<ModeloAjax> findByMarca(Long marca) {

    Session s = sf.getCurrentSession();

    Query q = s.createQuery("select id, nombre from "+getEntityName()+" where marca_id="+marca);

    List<?>modelos = q.list();

    List<ModeloAjax> result = new ArrayList<ModeloAjax>(modelos.size());

    for(Object o : modelos){
        result.add((ModeloAjax) o);
    }




    return result;
}
```

What can I do to fix the error?

Comment: You are trying to write sql query inside HQL createQuery method, that is wrong in the first step. use the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting Object[] to ModeloAjax. This array contains 2 items for id and nombre.

You need to code like this:

```
Query q = s.createQuery("select e from " + getEntityName() + " e where e.marca_id = " + marca);
```

NOTE: You want to keep your query. You have to do like this:

```
for(Object o : modelos ) {
    Object[] record = (Object[])o;
    // record[0] = id
    // record[1] = nombre

    // Convert record to ModeloAjax
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, Might be more specific? I need retur a POJO (ModeloAjax), not Entity

Comment: Because you coded "select id, nombre from" so modelos is LIST of Object[], NOT list of ModeloAjax. If you want it is list of ModeloAjax, you have to use my code 'select e from ..."

Comment: If you want POJO (ModeloAjax), not Entity. You have to convert Object[] to ModeloAjax. For example: new ModeloAjax(record[0], record[1])

Answer (score 1):

```
Query q = s.createQuery("select id, nombre from "+getEntityName()+" where marca_id="+marca).addEntity(ModeloAjax.class);
```

Will return the db values in list of ModeloAjax objects.